# The URL couldn't be validated Facebook Messenger Chat Bot

Tags: node.js, webhooks, facebook-chatbot

i tried to make some bot messenger on facebook, but when i try to setup the webhook it is always failed, any suggestion?

[image]

and here is my code, what did i do wrong in my setup?

```
const express   = require('express');
const bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');
const app   = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

const APP_SECRET    = "";
const VALID_TOKEN   = "semarangbot";
const SERVER_URL    = "https://b915e9f8.ngrok.io";
const ACCESS_TOKEN  = "";
const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  console.log('Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', server.address().port, app.settings.env);
})
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Server Ok!');
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.get('/webhook', (req, res) => {
    if (req.query['hub.mode'] && req.query['hub.verify_token'] === VALID_TOKEN) {
        res.status(200).send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
    } else {
        res.status(403).end();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `/webhook` to the URL in the 'Callback URL' field. That's the endpoint you have setup for verification. Right now, you are telling Messenger Platform to call `/` for verification which is only returning a `200OK`.